# gpu::blur function takes significantly more time

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu

Here is a function which I tried to optimize for GPU. gpu::blur is taking significantly long time in this code. When I run normal CPU version of this code it takes about 1.5 seconds to execute for 30 images ( framesToProcess contains 30 images ). When I run this code ( which uses gpu:: functions and GpuMat ) it takes more than 30 seconds. If i comment gpu::blur line it takes only 0.5 seconds to execute. Please help me to find what is wrong in GPU version.

```
void getContourCenters(vector<gpu::GpuMat>  &framesToProcess, vector<pointI>& contourCenter)
{
    size_t j = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < framesToProcess.size(); i++)
    {

            gpu::GpuMat tempDifferenceImage, tempThresholdImage, tempBlurredImage;
            vector< vector<Point> > contours;
            vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
            Rect objectBoundingRectangle = Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            gpu::absdiff(framesToProcess[i - 1], framesToProcess[i], tempDifferenceImage);
            gpu::threshold(tempDifferenceImage, tempThresholdImage, SENSITIVITY_VALUE, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
            gpu::blur(tempThresholdImage, tempBlurredImage, Size(BLUR_SIZE, BLUR_SIZE));

            Mat contourImage( tempBlurredImage );
            findContours(contourImage, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            for (int k = 0; k < contours.size(); ++k)
            {
                    objectBoundingRectangle = boundingRect(contours[k]);
                    int xpos = objectBoundingRectangle.x + objectBoundingRectangle.width / 2;
                    int ypos = objectBoundingRectangle.y + objectBoundingRectangle.height / 2;
                    contourCenter.push_back(mp(xpos, ypos, j++));
            }
    }
}
```

BLUR_SIZE is a constant with value 50. Image  size is 992 X 1000, CV_8UC1 type image. I am running on Nvidia Tegra K1. Here is the other version of the code:

```
    void getContourCenters(vector<Mat>  &framesToProcess, vector<pointI>& contourCenter)
{    
    size_t j = 0;       
    for (int i = 1; i < framesToProcess.size(); i++)
    {    
                    Mat tempDifferenceImage, tempThresholdImage;
                    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
                    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
                    Rect objectBoundingRectangle = Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    absdiff(framesToProcess[i - 1], framesToProcess[i], tempDifferenceImage);
                    threshold(tempDifferenceImage, tempThresholdImage, SENSITIVITY_VALUE, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
                    blur(tempThresholdImage, tempThresholdImage, Size(BLUR_SIZE, BLUR_SIZE));
                    findContours(tempThresholdImage, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

                    for (int k = 0; k < contours.size(); ++k)
                    {
                            objectBoundingRectangle = boundingRect(contours[k]);
                            int xpos = objectBoundingRectangle.x + objectBoundingRectangle.width / 2;
                            int ypos = objectBoundingRectangle.y + objectBoundingRectangle.height / 2;
                            contourCenter.push_back(mp(xpos, ypos, j++));
                    }           

    }
```

}

This code takes 1.5 seconds to execute on the same machine. I wanted to optimize the this code for GPU and wrote the version mentioned above, which is taking more than 30 seconds.

Comment: Please add some information: Size of BLUR_SIZE, size of images in framesToProcess, hardware used.

Comment: @MarkusMayr I have edited the question and also included the normal version of the same function which uses CPU functions and runs perfectly fine.

Comment: are you using `OpenCV 4 Tegra` binaries, provided by nvidia? It has built-in tegra functions that are called from some kind of tegra library, which is much faster than OpenCV CUDA support.

Comment: In addition, if you dont use tegra but `IPP` (e.g. on a standard intel pc) it will use the graphics card too, which again ist more efficient than the OpenCV CUDA support.

Comment: for clarification: the "cpu" version internally has something like `if tegra_support: call super_fast_special_tegra_library_function` (have a look at the open source code). At least that's true for sobel filter, but I'm pretty sure that's the same for gaussian filter, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as already stated in my comments, OpenCV has optimized Tegra support (if the opencv4tegra libraries are used), so it is very likely that your OpenCV GPU functions aren't really "slow" but your "CPU" version in fact is very fast, because it calls some tegra optimized functions internally (instead of using the CPU).

From http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3411-OpenCV-For-Tegra.pdf you can see that there are several optimizations in opencv4tegra, including

1. NEON SIMD instructions
2. GLSL algorithms, using opengl shader to speed things up
3. Tegra hardware optimizations

which all use the same known "CPU" API.

other details can be found in http://docs.opencv.org/opencv2refman-tegra.pdf

> a list of OpenCV functions that are optimized for Tegra platform in the current OpenCV release. Optimization
>   covers the most popular data types and operation modes, that are specified for each function below. When an optimized
>   function is called on a data type or a mode that is
>   not
>   covered by optimization, the original implementation is called.

- cv::absdiff
- cv::add
- cv::addWeighted
- cv::bitwise_and
- cv::bitwise_not
- cv::bitwise_or
- cv::bitwise_xor
- cv::compare
- cv::countNonZero
- cv::Mat::dot
- cv::inRange
- cv::max
- cv::mean
- cv::meanStdDev
- cv::merge
- cv::min
- cv::minMaxLoc
- cv::phase
- cv::reduce
- cv::split
- cv::subtrac
- cv::sum
- cv::Mat::convertTo
- cv::blur
- cv::boxFilter
- cv::Canny
- cv::cvtColor
- cv::dilate
- cv::erode
- cv::filter2D
- **cv::GaussianBlur**
- cv::integral
- cv::matchTemplate
- cv::medianBlur
- cv::pyrDown
- cv::pyrUp
- cv::resize
- cv::Scharr
- cv::Sobel
- cv::threshold
- cv::warpAffine
- cv::warpPerspective
- cv::FAST
- cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK
- cv::buildOpticalFlowPyramid
- cv::detail::createLaplacePyr
- cv::detail::normalizeUsingWeightMap
- cv::detail::BestOf2NearestMatcher::match
- cv::findCirclesGrid

in the document it is marked which of the functions are GPU-powered

Comment: I installed the version of opencv that is available in nvidia website and followed the installation instructions. As I can see blur cv::blur has already been optimized for GPU. But why is it taking longer when explicit gpu module is called?

Comment: because the gpu module doesnt use tegra optimization but only cuda and only (afaik) cuda 1.2 or sth. ... in addition there is some overhead in opencv cuda functionality. And again: probably tegra optimization is very well done (done by nvidia itself - closed source).

Comment: Thanks for the insight... :)